# Julia run external programm with environmental variables: Don't interpolate $

Tags: julia

I'm trying to run a shell command from Julia which needs to have an environment variable set to some specific value. I have two problems:

1. How to set environment variables to be used by Julia's 
    `run(command, args...; wait::Bool = true)` command?
2. How to pass special sign `$` to this process without interpolating it? I want to test if the variable is available for my program.

#### What I have done so far:

Let's say I want to define an environment variable `FOO=bar` and check if it's accessible within the shell with shell command `echo $FOO`.

To prevent Julia interpolating `$` I already quoted it like explained in the [official documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/#Quoting-1) but then echo is printing `$PATH` and not its value.

So for `FOO` I got the following output

```
julia> run(`echo '$FOO'`)
$FOO
Process(`echo '$FOO'`, ProcessExited(0))
```

but would have expected something like

```
julia> run(`echo '$FOO'`)

Process(`echo '$FOO'`, ProcessExited(0))
```

if `FOO` is undefined *or*

```
julia> run(`echo '$FOO'`)
bar
Process(`echo '$FOO'`, ProcessExited(0))
```

if the value is set to `bar`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "but then the shell is not doing what I expected"? What is it doing? What did you expect it to do? See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would have expected to get the actual value of `PATH`, so something like `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Also to keep it more consistent I changed my example to `FOO`

Comment: See my answer. It shows how you are supposed to do this in Julia, including links to the documentation. If it works for you, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Julia documentation on environment variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/index.html). You can set an environment variable with:

```
julia> ENV["FOO"] = "bar"
"bar"
```

and you can retrieve the value of an environment variable with:

```
julia> ENV["FOO"]
"bar"
julia> ENV["PATH"]
"really long string of my path"
```

As you've already stated, you can avoid interpreting the `$` by single-quoting that part of your `run` command. I'm not totally sure what you are looking for there.

Comment: I understand that this is the preferred way to do it in Julia. But out of curiosity, is there a way to actually do ```run(`echo '$FOO'`)``` so it outputs the same as on the shell? Maybe I should ask a new question for that though...

Comment: This has the disadvantage of mutating the parent process's `ENV`. Is there any way to pass env variables to the `run` child process without affecting the parent process?

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but this works:

```
julia> write("temp.sh", "echo foo=\$BAR");

julia> run(`bash temp.sh`)
foo=
Process(`bash temp.sh`, ProcessExited(0))

julia> ENV["BAR"] = "bar";

julia> run(`bash temp.sh`)
foo=bar
Process(`bash temp.sh`, ProcessExited(0))
```

I guess Julia injects the content of `ENV` into the shell before running the command. And that's all I needed to know as I'll be launching other executables which require some environment variables to be set. So when setting them inside `ENV[]`, they will be available to the executables you run from within that Julia session.